# Post-Redirect-Get with Spring WebFlux and Thymeleaf

Tags: thymeleaf, spring-webflux

Can someone explain to me how to implement the **post-redirect-get** pattern in Spring WebFlux and Thymeleaf? **What subscribes on the database save method?**

```
@GetMapping("/register")
public String showRegisterForm(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("user", new User());

    return "register";
}

@PostMapping
public String processRegisterForm(@Valid User user, BindingResult bindingResult) {
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        return "register";
    } else {
        userRepository.save(user); //what subscribes on this?
        //how to redirect on e.g. "/login"?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make your controller method return a reactive type like this:

```
@PostMapping
public Mono<String> processRegisterForm(@Valid User user, BindingResult bindingResult) {
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        return Mono.just("register");
    } else {
        return userRepository.save(user).thenReturn("redirect:/login");
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know why I didn't try this at the first place. Thank you very much. :)

Answer (score 1):

Just for the record I recommend the solution that Brian wrote as is express the intent much better. However if you want to impress your friends. The here is some without the if statement.

```
@PostMapping
public Mono<String> processRegisterForm(@Valid User user, BindingResult bindingResult) {

    return Mono
            .just(bindingResult.hasErrors())
            .filter(t -> t)
            .flatMap( t-> Mono.just("register"))
            .switchIfEmpty(userRepository.save(user).thenReturn("redirect:/login"));
}
```